# 500 internal server error on installing slim framework

Tags: php, slim

i am developing a simple RESTful API on slim framework. I had no problem installing the [slim framework](http://slimframework.com) on my local wamp server and it works just fine, but as I do the same on my website I get an 500 internal server error.

**My httaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /slim/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
php_flag register_globals on
```

I need help, could someone please enlighten me on how to fix this problem?

Comment: `register_globals on`? Oh my...

Comment: What's in the Apache error log?

Comment: if i turn register global off i get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /data/25/2/139/114/2628766/user/2884154/htdocs/slim/index.php on line 40

Comment: What's on line #40 of `slim/index.php`?

Comment: line #40: $app->get('/', function () {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your web host is a CPanel one (a pretty good chance), it's probably using SuPHP in which case any `php_flag` or `php_value` directives in `.htaccess` will trigger a 500 error.

See http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2009/08/php-suexec-and-custom-php-ini-files/

`register_globals` is a terrible hack and one you definitely should not be using. If the framework requires it, choose a better framework.

### Update

The syntax on line #40 is using a PHP 5.3 anonymous function. Your web host is probably using a lower PHP version.

See the advice under [Step 3: Define Routes section on this page](http://www.slimframework.com/read/hello-world).

Comment: it works on local wamp server when i dont mentions php_flag register_globals on in .htaccess.i wonder whats wrong with networksolutions.here is the index                                      <?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php'; 

$app = new Slim();

$app->get('/', function () {
  echo "hello world";
});

$app->run();                                                                  i get error in line $app->get('/', function () {

Comment: The PHP version was my issue! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and I was able to correct this by uncommenting the following line in the file "httpd.conf" (apache conf) :

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Maybe this indication will help someone later ;)